# Weil's completion of locally totally bounded groups to locally compact groups

Tags: topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $G$ be a topological group. Say that $A\subseteq G$ is **totally bounded** if for any neighborhood of $e$, $U$, there exists a finite subset $F\subseteq G$ such that $A\subseteq FU$. $G$ is **locally totally bounded** if there exists a neighborhood of $e$ that is totally bounded.

It seems to be a well-established fact that a locally totally bounded group may be densely extended to a unique locally compact group. That is, if $G$ is locally totally bounded, there exists some unique (up to isomorphism) locally compact group $\overline{G}$ such that $G$ is a dense subgroup of $\overline{G}$. Apparently, this was originally proved in Weil's *Sur les espaces à structure uniforme et sur la topologie générale* (1938), (chapter 3).

I can't  find that book anywhere. Does anyone know the proof for this? Is it very complicated?

[Here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789491216350), (pg. 398) they seem to discuss this in terms of Raikov  completions, but it seemed a bit complicated for me.